Есть ли в русском языке слово "алчба"? Какова его стилевая характеристика в разных текстах?
Это перевод с английского языка (Р. Сидни, пер.  Евг. Фельдмана)
Несёт своим же радостям урон,
Кто алчет удовольствий то и дело.
И коль меня алчба не одолела,
То я любви служу верней, чем он.

Насколько верно использовал это слово переводчик? Как оно влияет на стиль стихотворения? Ведь это важно для правильного восприятия поэтического текста. К примеру, я не могу понять, насколько серьезен автор, нет ли тут иронии и насмешки?
По оригиналу сложно судить))
 Vain may their hopes all prove, their joys more vain,
 Whom sense of pleasure doth to love allure:
 Blest in my bands, rather may I endure
 For you, that toiled with joys love elsewhere gain.

P. S. Добавлю для равновесия ироничного (как мне кажется) Филипа Сидни, к тому же он нам расскажет правило грамматики.
Сонет 63. О правила грамматики!
О правила грамматики! Вдвойне
Пускай себя проявит ваша сила:
Не школяры (она им так постыла!),
Но милая ее докажет мне.

Когда недавно, с ней наедине,
Опять запретной милости просил я,
"Нет! Нет!" голубка дважды повторила,
Страшась, что не расслышу я вполне...

Воспрянь же, Муза, и пеан пропой,
Забудьте зависть, Небеса, и мой
Успех триумфом увенчайте сразу:
Поскольку знают все со школьных лет,
Что тот, кто свел в суждении два "нет",
Построил утвердительную фразу!

Перевод Л. Темина

● Слово алчба в русском языке имеется: книжн. устар., то же, что алчность.
• Часто используется и в других значениях:
жадность, сильное желание; голод, жажда, ненасытность.

Церковнославянское слово «алкать» образовано от существительного «алчба», которое переводится на русский язык как «сильный голод», другое его значение — «огромное желание по отношению к чему-либо». Два этих смысла до сих пор присутствуют в русском языке. Хотя первое значение, сильного голода, по популярности значительно уступает второму — желанию обладать какой-то вещью. В толковом словаре Даля мы, например, находим поговорку: «Наделил Бог волка алкатою», — в которой подчеркивается ненасытность этого животного. По преимуществу «алкать» используется все же по отношению к поведению человека. «Ум, алчущий познанья», — пишет Грибоедов. Именно в этом смысле слово «алчущий» употреблено и в Евангелии. «Блажени алчущие и жаждущие правды» следует понимать таким образом, что по обетованию Христа счастье смогут найти те, кто алчет и жаждет присутствия правды Божией в своей жизни. Современный русский язык употребляет слово «алкать» и в негативном смысле. Всем прекрасно знакомо понятие «алчный», которое обозначает человека жадного, не знающего меры в стяжании денег и власти.
[источник; Даль — алкать]

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса
Штука была в том, чтобы выдавать крошки бесполезной для них правды в самое нестерпимое мгновение пытки, когда еще хочется остаться в живых; ибо сразу за этим следует миг-оборотень, нестерпимая алчба смерти, когда даже пытатели устают от допроса и могут не выдержать — пристрелить или полоснуть по горлу ножом (Дина Рубина. Русская канарейка. Блудный сын).
Я держу кулек с пунцовыми помидорами и вижу, что не любовью к Ипатьевской старине дышат Володькины небыстрые глаза, а откровенной помидорной алчбой (И. А. Дедков. Дневник).
Но, подняв голову, я увидел бесчисленную портретную галерею алчбы, горевшей в глазах зрителей; черты их лиц стали лесом, дрожащим от возбуждения (А. С. Грин. Серый автомобиль).
● («Былые дни, былые времена». Страницы английской и шотландской поэзии в переводах Евгения Фельдмана, стр. 49)
Роберт Сидни (1563–1626):
СОНЕТ 2
Я счастлив: я жестоко опалён
Огнём любви, горячим до предела.
Желание отвергнул я всецело,
И только верой дух воспламенён.
Несёт своим же радостям урон,
Кто алчет удовольствий то и дело.
И коль меня алчба не одолела,
То я любви служу верней, чем он.
Вы – божество; когда же для меня
Земля и небо станут неразъяты?
Узрю ль объятье, полное огня,
Объятье, что и жертвенно, и свято?
Я счастлив оттого, что жил для вас,
И радостно встречаю смертный час.
Мне кажется, что использование устаревших и высоких слов (алчба, разъять, узреть, объятье; смертный час) здесь к месту: четырёхсотлетнему сонету — особенные, ветхие слова, возвышенному чувству — торжественный стиль.

Спасибо за ответ. Если доверять переводу, то в сонете можно увидеть пылкую любовь, возвышенные чувства, а лексика этому вполне соответствует. Но я много читала про  Сидни, и  как-то эта любовь не вполне укладывается в общую картину.  //  Его на время отстранили от дипломатических поручений,  и он скучает чуть ли не в ссылке.  Именно тогда  он пишет трактат «Защита поэзии», ну и сонеты тоже, будто пробует перо.  // Да и личная жизнь  не в пользу глубоких чувств, есть мнение, что сонеты посвящены не Пенелопе Деверье, а сестре Мэри Герберт, которая к тому же, может, и не сестра вовсе.

Да и сам Сидни личность загадочная: королевские крестины и такие же похороны, да еще сюжет «Гамлета» похож на отношения в семье. То ли он в сражении убит, то ли еще где и кем… // Мне и первый его сонет кажется игривым и лукавым,  а теперь и этот тоже.  И тогда  вся торжественная лексика (алчба, разъять, узреть, объятье; смертный час)  —  какая-то веселая пародия на  такие чувства. Можно ли это увидеть в тексте или всё именно возвышенно и искренне?  Может, я ошибаюсь? Это мне особенно интересно.

Если будет настроение и интерес, прочитайте небольшой рассказ-версию про Сидни   "Мэри Пемброк. Жизнь в строке сонета". https://www.chitalnya.ru/work/1397027/

• Спасибо, интересно... • Я, правда, не совсем поняла, причем здесь Филип, автор "Защиты поэзии"... Это ведь сонет его брата, Роберта.

Действительно, Роберт Сидни. Но здесь, вероятно, ошибка))   Ну эти два сонета просто не отличишь один от другого. А Роберт фигура не такого масштаба, да и стиль у него совсем другой. // Но пусть даже так.  Так как насчет стиля, можно ли считать такую любовь куртуазной // Куртуазная любовь – специфическая средневековая форма возвышенной чувственной внебрачной любви рыцаря к прекрасной даме. Куртуазный– изысканно вежливый, любезный. [Фр. courtois – учтивый, любезный, галантный, от ст.-фр. court – двор] // Это своего рода игра, а не настоящие чувства.
